# How to enable AppArmor as kernel LSM?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, apparmor

I have installed AppArmor but when I start it it says

```
* AppArmor not available as kernel LSM.
```

how can I resolve this?

Comment: the same problem but not resolved

Comment: Then report it as a bug. Also what kernel version are you using? run  `uname -r` in Terminal(press <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<T> to opening Terminal)